# Help understanding the differences between more than/about and most/all of

Tags: comparative

I am very confused when doing homework because there are four sentences which are really alike but my teacher said that they are different and I still don't understand why.

> 1. "More than three-fourths of the world's mail is written in English"
> 2. "About three-fourths of the world's mail is written in English".

I think that they are the same. And another two sentences that make me really confused:

> 1. "Most other  languages have borrowed English words."
> 2. "All of the the other languages have borrowed English words'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***More*** than three-fourths means a quantity greater than 75%—at least 76%, perhaps 80% or 90%.

***About*** three-fourths means a quantity approximately equal to 75%—perhaps 73%, perhaps 77%, but certainly not so small as 70% or so large as 80%.

***Most*** other languages means more than half of the languages (usually substantially more than half—perhaps 60% or 80% or 90%), but **not all** of them—less than 100%.

***All*** other languages means every single one of them, without exception—100%.